# How to write a large amount of random bytes to file

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, fs, file-generation

I need to generate some files of varying sizes to test an application, I thought the easiest way to do so would be to write a Node script to do so.

I wrote the following code but the process crashes when the file size exceeds my memory.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const crypto = require('crypto');

const gb = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;

const data = crypto.randomBytes(gb * 5);

fs.writeFile('bytes.bin', data, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('The file has been saved!');
});
```

Comment: Just split it into smaller chunks...

Comment: I hope this may help you.
https://medium.com/dev-bits/writing-memory-efficient-software-applications-in-node-js-5575f646b67f

Comment: Why do it in Node, though? The easiest way is to use the `dd` utility: `dd if=/dev/urandom of=bytes.bin bs=64m count=80` (use `bs=64M` if on Mac). Super fast, does not use memory, no reason to home-brew it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On top of your memory issue you will also have an issue with the crypto module as the amount of bytes it can generate is limited.

You will need to use [fs.createWriteStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options) to generate and write the data in chunks rather than generating it in one go.

Here is a modified version of some code from the [Node documentation on streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_drain) to stream chunks of random bytes to a file:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const cryptoPackage = require('crypto');

const fileName = "random-bytes.bin";

const fileSizeInBytes = Number.parseInt(process.argv[2]) || 1000;
console.log(`Writing ${fileSizeInBytes} bytes`)

const writer = fs.createWriteStream(fileName)

writetoStream(fileSizeInBytes, () => console.log(`File created: ${fileName}`));

function writetoStream(bytesToWrite, callback) {
    const step = 1000;
    let i = bytesToWrite;
    write();
    function write() {
        let ok = true;
        do {
            const chunkSize = i > step ? step : i;
            const buffer = cryptoPackage.randomBytes(chunkSize);

            i -= chunkSize;
            if (i === 0) {
                // Last time!
                writer.write(buffer, callback);
            } else {
                // See if we should continue, or wait.
                // Don't pass the callback, because we're not done yet.
                ok = writer.write(buffer);
            }
        } while (i > 0 && ok);

        if (i > 0) {
            // Had to stop early!
            // Write some more once it drains.
            writer.once('drain', write);
        }
    }
}
```

There are also online tools which let you [generate files of your required size](https://fastest.fish/test-files#custom) with less setup. The files are also generated on your system so they don't have to be downloaded over the wire.